# Remove rows that are not multiple of 7 in OpenOffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice Calc I have a list of 9000 rows with many values.

I want to remove all the rows that are not multiple of 7.

Example:

```
Row 1
Row 2
Row 3
Row 4
Row 5
Row 6
Row 7
Row 8
Row 9
Row 10
Row 11
Row 12
Row 13
Row 14
Row 15
```

Becomes:

```
Row 7
Row 14
```

How would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Fill a spare column (eg `B`) with:

```
=MOD(ROW();7)
```

Filter the sheet on that column:

[image: Filter example]

Select all and Delete Cells... (entire row) then remove filter (and delete ColumnB, if you wish).